# GWTP + Gxt: Exception when using same presenter widget at two separate slots of page

Tags: gwt, gxt, gwt-platform

I have a page with border layout and slots defined for each of the regions of the border layout (for eg. EAST, WEST, NORTH, CENTER...).

I wish to reuse a presenter widget by displaying it at two of the above slots on the page.
I was successfully able to display the presenter widget on one of the slots but whenever I try to add the presenter widget at two separate slots I get this error:

`Exception caught: notifyReveal() called on a visible Presenter!`

Can anyone show me how it is to be done.

Below is my code.

**HomeView.java**

```
@UiField
ContentPanel centerPanel;

@UiField
ContentPanel westPanel;

@Override
public void setInSlot(Object slot, Widget content) {

    if (slot == HomePresenter.SLOT_EAST) {
        if (content != null) {
            eastPanel.add(content);
        }
    } else if (slot == HomePresenter.SLOT_WEST) {
        if (content != null) {
            westPanel.add(content);
        }
    } else if (slot == HomePresenter.SLOT_CENTER) {
        if (content != null) {
            centerPanel.add(content);
        }
    } else {
        super.setInSlot(slot, content);
    }
}

@Override
public void addToSlot(Object slot, Widget content) {
    if (slot == HomePresenter.SLOT_EAST) {
        if (content != null) {
            eastPanel.add(content);
        }
    } else if (slot == HomePresenter.SLOT_WEST) {
        if (content != null) {
            westPanel.add(content);
        }
    } else if (slot == HomePresenter.SLOT_CENTER) {
        if (content != null) {
            centerPanel.add(content);
        }
    } else {
        super.addToSlot(slot, content);
    }
}
```

**HomePresenter.java:**

```
public static final Object SLOT_WEST = new Object();

public static final Object SLOT_CENTER = new Object();

@Override
protected void revealInParent() {
    RevealRootContentEvent.fire(this, this); //Getting error over here
}

@Override
protected void onReset() {
    super.onReset();

    setInSlot(SLOT_WEST, null);
    setInSlot(SLOT_CENTER, null);

    indirectProvider.get(new AsyncCallback<LeftPanelPresenter>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LeftPanelPresenter result) {
            addToSlot(SLOT_WEST, result);
            addToSlot(SLOT_CENTER, result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Not added to the slot");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The point of the provider is to create a new instance of each `PresenterWidget` for each place you want to put it.

I think calling `addToSlot()` twice with the same `result` object is causing the error, because that instance has already been revealed.

You can use a loop to make a new instance for each slot:

```
// create an array of the slots
List<Object> slots = new ArrayList<Object>();
slots.add(SLOT_WEST);
slots.add(SLOT_CENTER);

// call provider.get() on each slot in turn
for(Object slot : slots)
{
    indirectProvider.get(new AsyncCallback<LeftPanelPresenter>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LeftPanelPresenter result)
        {
            addToSlot(slot, result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Not added to the slot");
        }
    });
}
```